# Working with attachment in Outlook using VSTO

Tags: c#, file-io, hash, outlook, vsto

I'm attempting to create a VSTO plugin for Outlook 2010 that will calculate the MD5 and SHA1 of email attachments. While calculating them is not the problem if I have the file accessible, or at least read into memory, the way Outlook sandboxes access to the system is stumping me.

I have tried storing it to `System.IO.Path.GetTempPath` but it just returns a void. I have been told that storing it to memory is also not possible.

Reference for `Attachment.SaveAsFile`:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.attachment.saveasfile(v=office.14).aspx

I'm trying hard to not hardcode storing every file to `C:\Temp` due to performance issues on large files. Does anyone have a good way of working with the attachment from within Outlook?

Answer (score 0):

I usually save outlook attachments in my application directory, under a temp directory.
Then I clear this directory when my application close. It avoid problem with attachments locked etc.

```
private static string getAttachmentPath(Outlook.Attachment attachment)
{
    var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName( Application.ExecutablePath), attachment.FileName);
    attachment.SaveAsFile(path);
    return path;
}
```

Comment: I'll check this out later, though currently I have mine going to c:\temp. Problem is that I'm using this to look at potentially malicious attachments so storing makes me a bit antsy.